# Minimum value of $\frac{(1 + x + x^2)(1 + y + y^2)}{xy}$

Tags: calculus, quadratic-forms

> What is the minimum value of $$\frac{(1 + x + x^2)(1 + y + y^2)}{xy},~~(x \neq 0)$$

Should we find the minimum value of each quadratic?

Comment: There is obviously no minimum. If $y=1$ and $x\to0-$ then the given expression tends to $-\infty$. – Check your source for the exact formulation of the problem. Maybe you want $x>0$, $y>0$.

Comment: nice .........+1

Answer (score 5):

$$\frac{(1+x+x^2)(1+y+y^2)}{xy} = \frac{1+x+x^2}{x} \cdot \frac{1+y+y^2}{y}$$

By AM–GM inequality $(1+x+\frac1x)(1+y+\frac1y)≥3*3=9$

Comment: how is this a hint? please explain someting more

Comment: Woah! Got it. Thanks.

Comment: Bhaskara-III, Take 1, 1/x and x as elements. By AM=GM (bcoz minimum), (1 + 1/x + x)/3=1*1/x*x => 1 + 1/x + x = 3. Similarly, 1 + 1/y + y=3. Therefore the whole thing is equal to (1+x+x2)(1+y+y2)/xy=3*3=9